# Link two divs via jquery - whatever happens inside one happens in the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I remember when I was playing with Flash around 10 years ago. I could create a clip, than duplicate it, and whatever I would do with clip 1 would auto-instantly change duplicated item - so in essence these where two windows of the same thing.

I wonder if same is possible with dom elements. I would like to clone element, and whatever happens to original should happen to clone too. In whatever I mean, click events and classes mostly.

This is html:

```
<li id="67" data-word-id="2" data-order-id="1" class="ui-state-default">
    <article>
    Some content...
    <div class="invisible active" data-invisi-status"1"="" title="Do you want to keep this item private and invisible to anyone except for you?">Make word invisible</div>
    </article>
</li>
```

I want to keep invisible icon active class and status synced between copied elements.

I achieve copying from 1 list to the other by:

```
$(this).removeClass("ui-sortable-helper").css({"height":"auto"}).clone().appendTo($list).show("slow");
```

How I would keep this synced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using classes affects all DOM elements of that class. So I guess you could think of a flash clip as a DOM element with a specific class.

```
$('.my-clip').removeClass('ui-sortable-helper');
```

Would remove the class `ui-sortable-helper` from all elements with the class `.my-clip`

However, there are certain methods which only work on *one* element, and it's generally the first in the selection.

If you bind an event handler to something inside `.my-clip`, say a link for instance, and then refer to it using the `this` variable, you're only updating the element that triggered the event.

For example:

```
$('.my-clip').on('click', 'a', function(e){
  $(this).addClass('link-clicked');
});
```

This would only add the class `link-clicked` to the link that triggered the event, however, if you did:

```
$('.my-clip').on('click', 'a', function(e){
  $('.my-clip').find('a').addClass('link-clicked');
});
```

It would add the class `link-clicked` to all `a` elements within all instances of `.my-clip`

Comment: Can even expand on this, if there are links and what not, use `.myclass <element>` and an instance of `this`

Comment: @tymeJV - sure, done. It's probably not the best example -- I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: Looks good, this is probably the closest way you're going to get to have elements "clone" one another along with the handlers

Comment: This is awesome. But my problem is that sometimes I need to use $(this) when there is no clone. And sometimes I've to use class. I will have to write many conditionals... But I guess this is the solution and there is no other easier way.